# Access facebook public data using python

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

i want to retrieve public data of facebook users.
I use the following code:

```
>>> import facebook
>>> token = 'mytoken' #example token
>>> graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
>>> profile = graph.get_object("me")
```

and with that code i retrieve all the public information about me.
When i want to retrieve other user's public data(i mean the data that i can see on other facebook profiles via the browser, without being friends or friends' friends) i use the following code for an example id:

```
>>> graph.get_object('example id')
```

the issue is that i get only the name,firstname, id and the facebook link of the user.

I actually want to retrieve data such as : birthday,gendre etc.

That kind of data are accessible when using

```
>>> profile = graph.get_object("me")
```

Comment: You can not get birthday or gender without them giving you permission to get it

Comment: Even though that this kind of info is accessible from their public data?. I mean that i use profile ids that their birthday are accessible from the broswer

Comment: Just because something is available on facebook.com doesn't mean you can just access it through the API. So yes. You need permission to access it

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer i have been looking for. I also found that there is a public api that is not in use now https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/